# window.open returns null on iOS safari events: pagehide, unload and beforeunload

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari, window.open

I'm trying to get a popup window to fire when a user navigates away from the current URL.

window.open seems to return null on safari iOS only, every other browser (desktop and mobile) seems to work fine given that a popup blocker isn't active.
 Is this a known issue? If so are there any work arounds to getting a popup window on either the `pagehide`, `unload` or `beforeunload` event?

```
window.addEventListener('pagehide', function () {
    // window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    var myWindow = window.open("", "");
    myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "pagehide";
});
window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
    // window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    var myWindow = window.open("", "");
    myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "unload";
});
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
    // window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    var myWindow = window.open("", "");
    myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "beforeunload";
});
```

I created a simple fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ovidubs/2cdas6vj/

Comment: pop up blocker is going to block them, that was blocked ages ago from spam.

Comment: When popup blocker was turned off it use to work, but even now with it turned off, window.open is returning null.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue